# Memory Consumption in S2E

Tags: c++

When I tested a simple program with S2E, I watching the RAM usage, it seems S2E will continue to run and consume RAM until there isn't enough left for anything else, and Linux must kill it.

The odd part is that even as it's killing states(I use a function s2e_kill_state() to do this), the RAM usage is still growing.

WHY??Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Maybe you have a memory leak in your code.

Comment: You may want to clarify what S2E is. There's no tag for it, which is a hint that you're using somewhat uncommon technology.

Comment: I suggest you post your question in the [S2E Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/s2e-dev), some of the S2E developers may be able to help you.